# Aptana files search

Tags: netbeans, aptana

Is there files search in Aptana like in NetBeans <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>?
[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think the OP wants something else. What you want is "Open Resource," not "File Search"

Navigate > Open Resource should give you something far closer to the NetBeans experience.

Comment: That's **exactly** what I want!

Comment: you can reach it using ctrl+shift+R

Comment: also you can open by ctrl+t

Answer (score 4):

Also if you're on a windows machine, the hotkey for this is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>. That will also open the file search command and is a lot faster.

Comment: And this is what I was searching for!

Answer (score 3):

In the main menu :  `Search > File`

If you want a keyboard shortcut for it, go to menu `Window > Preferences` , and in the category `General > Keys` filter the "file search". And set one you like.

The interface for results will be a bit different though.

Comment: Yes, but it's away less convinient than you just start writing files name and get list of files matched (like in NetBeans). I have a project with `settings.py` file. In APtana I have to write "settings.py", but in NetBeans I would just start typing "sett"... I think I'd better change my IDE to NetBeans.

Comment: It's a subjective choice. Matter of habits. For example , i use search only when looking for some ancient code fragment, and ( while UI choices for initiating search suck ) the form of result delivery fits my usecase perfectly.

Comment: Totally agree, that's why I've accepted the answer and decided to stick with NetBeans.